# Connect Macbook Pro to TV wirelessly

Tags: wifi, remote-desktop, television, projector

I am currently using an HDMI adapter (and a cable for audio) to connect my Macbook Pro (2009) to my HD TV (no smart TV) and I use a wireless keyboard and mouse.

Is it possible to achieve the same result wirelessly? Note that I'm not looking for something like Apple TV. I want to see my desktop on the TV, possibly with audio as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe me you are looking for something like Apple TV and Apple computer made in or after 2011 with Mountain Lion installed. It's called [Airplay Mirroring](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/14/inside_os_x_108_mountain_lion_gm_airplay_mirroring.html).

Or alternatively you can achive something similar with [this app](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167702/an_alternative_for_airplay_mirroring.html)

Comment: is AirParrot compatible with 2009 MacBook Pros?

Comment: Well, developer claims only OS requirement which is 10.6.8 +. So it must naturally be supported. But don't take my word for it, ask the developer if in doubt.